# Why is my update statement updating my columns with the wrong data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why is my update statement updating my columns `card_id` with the wrong data?

My database structure.

[image: db structure]

`$deckCardIds` Holds a array of different two digit numbers.

**What I expect the code to:** Update each column based on the the current row I am looping through and updating `card_id` with the current index of `$deckCardIds`.

**What is actually happening:** The columns are looped through and data is set with `$deckCardIds` but then set to `0` when the loops moves to the next iteration.

```
<?php
$playerId=$_GET['playerid'];   
$playerDeckCardIds=$_GET['deckcardids'];   

$deckCardIds = explode(" ", $playerDeckCardIds);
array_pop($deckCardIds);

try
{
    #Connect to the db
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcg', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT row_id FROM player_deck WHERE player_id = :player_id');
    $stmt->execute(array('player_id' => $playerId));

    $r = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $i=0;

    foreach($r as $row) 
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE player_deck SET card_id = :card_id WHERE row_id = :row_id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':card_id', $deckCardIds[$i]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':row_id', $row->row_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}  
?>
```

Comment: did you check if your form has a proper 1:1 between your row IDs and the card values, and the same 1:1 ordering when the query string arrives at the server? You have nothing that explicitly links a card id with a row id, so  if there's **ANY** shifting going on somewhere, you will update the db with bad data. ... and that wouldn't be your code's problem. it'd be your fault for not properly structuring the data to preserve the necessary linkages.

Comment: @MarcB Yes the data should be 1:1. The index for $deckCardIds will never be larger than 59. The player will always have 60 rows that hold card_id. I should also mention that 0 does not exist as a proper value held by $deckCardIds.

Comment: but your'e asuming that the order the records come out of the db is the same order that they're in on the html form and the same order that they're submitted in

Comment: I think I see what your saying. row_id is the primary and auto increments. I assumed it would select the rows based on the lowest row_id and increment the array until it got to the last row_id. Then my foreach would loop through those rows in correct order. Is this not how it works?

Comment: that's how foreach works, but if ANYTHING causes data on either side to show up in a different order, you'll go from x1->y1,x2->y2 into weird pairings like x1->y17, x10->y3,  etc...

Comment: No query is guaranteed to return data in any specific order unless you explicitly `ORDER BY`.  Result sets must always be assumed to be in a non-deterministic order otherwise.  That's true of relational databases in general, not just MySQL.  The server will satisfy your query with the least amount of work, and that's the technical reason why the ordering can shift.